# Selenium Visio Style Connect Objects

Tags: c#, selenium

I am looking at automating a new project and this is the first time I have seen something like this. I am hoping someone has done something similar and can share how they accomplished it.

What I have is a side div with objects that can be dragged into a main div area. Once the objects are dragged in, the user can then rename them but also draw a link to multiple objects. Basically hold mouse down on one object and drag to the object they want to connect. It then draws a line connecting the two objects. The best way to describe is like a visio diagram connecting databases and servers.

I am not sure how to draw the lines or drag boxes to specific xy coordinates. I am thinking that is the best way?

Suggestions please!!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be easier than I expected. Simple drag and drops by x y coordinates and then drag and drop object 1 to object 2 created my line connection.